# Return values not present in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

- A - table shows if a given topic has been processed
- B - all posibile topicNames related to a given projectId

What I'd like to return is table, which shows topics left to be processed. So assuming table B contains all possible topicNames I want to exclude those from table A and show only B-A(ghi, jkl). To ilustrate this please look at table C below:

I'm really struggling to get the right query. Any hints on that?

```
A:
fieldId | projectId | topicName
-------------------------------
   1    |     A     |   abc
   1    |     A     |   def

B:
fieldId | projectId | topicName
--------------------------------
   1    |     A     |   abc
   1    |     A     |   def
   1    |     A     |   ghi
   1    |     A     |   jkl


What I want - Table C:

C:
fieldId | projectId | topicName
-------------------------------
   1    |     A     |   ghi
   1    |     A     |   jkl
```

Comment: How do we know that `fieldId = 1` from the `A` table is associated with the topics from the `B` table when they _don't_ match?  I think some information is missing fro your question/data.

Comment: the connection between these tables is based on projectId. So to my understanding it always matches. Like for project A we have abc,def,ghi,jkl possibilities. When for example topics abc and def is processed i want to show only those which left (ghi,jkl). So the field id for ghi,jkl is the same as the one in table A, in this case always 1.  Idk if i can explain that.

Comment: PLease have a look now. I have changed the tables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [EXCEPT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) based upon 2 queries. This is basically the opposite of UNION.

> EXCEPT returns all rows that are in the result of query1 but not in
> the result of query2. (This is sometimes called the difference between
> two queries.) Again, duplicates are eliminated unless EXCEPT ALL is
> used.

For your case something like: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6965f3f3377d1a8109ce937fb8a0faa8))

```
select fieldId , projectId , topicName from B 
except
select fieldId , projectId , topicName from A;
```